# How does load affect an RC-filtered PWM DAC?

Tags: pwm

When using a PWM as a DAC, how does load affect the output voltage & current? How do you know whether the design needs a buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The analog signal from the filtered PWM will have some source impedance.  You can break that into two parts to understand it more easily.  Think of it as a 0 impedance source in series with a resistor of the actual impedance value.  Now you can see that this resistor and and load resistance form a voltage divider.  This is in fact the basis of Thevenin's theorum.  Use that as a search term and you will find much about it, so there is no need for me to get more deeply into it here.

Any load will make the output sag a little.  At some point it will make it sag to the level you care, and buffering is one way to allow for a lower load impedance than that.  The output will sag to half its unloaded value when the load impdance equals the signal source impedance.